# Silverstripe image upload as javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, silverstripe

Trying to use the vegas slider http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/ in a Silverstripe project and I am having trouble setting up to allow the images to be added via the CMS.

Tried using

```
        $vars = array(
        'Slideshow1' => $this->Slideshow1,
        'Slideshow2' => $this->Slideshow2,
        'Slideshow3' => $this->Slideshow3,
        'Slideshow4' => $this->Slideshow4,
        'Slideshow5' => $this->Slideshow5,
        'Slideshow6' => $this->Slideshow6,
        'Slideshow7' => $this->Slideshow7
    );  

    Requirements::javascriptTemplate("themes/mysite/javascript/vegas1.js", $vars);
```

in the page controller.

And then in my script file had

```
    $('body').vegas({
    delay: 7000,
    timer: false,
    shuffle: true,
    transition: 'fade2',
    transitionDuration: 3000,
    slides: [
        { src: "$Slideshow1"},
        { src: "$Slideshow2"},
        { src: "$Slideshow3"},
        { src: "$Slideshow4"},
        { src: "$Slideshow5"},
        { src: "$Slideshow6"},
        { src: "$Slideshow7"}
    ],
    overlay: '/themes/mysite/images/overlays/01.png'
});
```

In my Page template I have

```
    public static $has_one = array(
    'Slideshow1' => 'Image',
    'Slideshow2' => 'Image',
    'Slideshow3' => 'Image',
    'Slideshow4' => 'Image',
    'Slideshow5' => 'Image',
    'Slideshow6' => 'Image',
    'Slideshow7' => 'Image',
);

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', new UploadField('Slideshow1', 'Slideshow Background Image:'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', new UploadField('Slideshow2', 'Slideshow Background Image:'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', new UploadField('Slideshow3', 'Slideshow Background Image:'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', new UploadField('Slideshow4', 'Slideshow Background Image:'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', new UploadField('Slideshow5', 'Slideshow Background Image:'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', new UploadField('Slideshow6', 'Slideshow Background Image:'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', new UploadField('Slideshow7', 'Slideshow Background Image:'));
```

The variable is getting passed into the html, but it shows as

```
<div class="vegas-slide-inner" style="background-image: url($Slideshow1); background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-position: center center; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

instead of the image loading from the assets folder.  Right now its hardcoded in so the slides work, but in the future would like to be able to add images via the CMS.  Thanks!

Comment: You should think about saving images as a `has_many` relation, or are you sure you always need exactly seven images in the slideshow?

Comment: The person who made this site was just converting it from HTML to a CMS site, so she was just using what they had.  She asked if I knew a way to make them editable via CMS so I tried what I thought would work.  Figured we'd try and get it working the way they had it, then switch it to something more customize-able.

Answer (score 2):

Good question! Don't use `javascriptTemplate`. That's an old hack that encourages bad practice. I wouldn't be surprised if it's deprecated soon.

The way you typically pass variables from controller to template is through simple `data-` attributes.

```
<div class="my-slideshow" data-some-var="$SomeVar" data-some-other-var="$SomeOtherVar">
```

And the data is fetched using `$('.my-slideshow').data('some-var')`, etc.

If you have a lot of variables, you can serialise the whole thing into JSON. Remember, it's perfectly compliant to put JSON into an attribute value.

php:

```
public function SlideshowConfig()
{

  $myJSVars = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'qux' => [
      'biz' => 'boz',
    ]
  ];

  return Convert::array2json($myJSVars);
}
```

ss:

```
<div class="slideshow-wrapper" data-slideshow-config="$SlideshowConfig">
```

js:

```
const slideshowConfig = $('.slideshow-wrapper').data('slideshow-config');
$(...).slideshow(JSON.parse(slideshowConfig));
```

One caveat about that second approach is that it's not XSS safe, so be sure that any variables you're passing through the controller are not sourced from user input.

Answer (score 1):

While @UncleCheese gave some inistructions how to pass config to the javascript slicer one problem still remains: You try to pass the Image Object to the config where it expects the string of the Image URL for it.

Looking at the `Image` Object in Silverstripe you can see it

1. is a subclass of `File`
2. it has methods for resizing

`File` has some methods to get the URL of the object, `getURL()` and `getAbsoluteURL()`. So in a template (ss or javascript template, not in PHP Code) you can skip the "get" in the method name and use something like:

```
{ src: "$Slideshow1.AbsoluteURL"}
```

which will output the URL to the uploaded, not resized Image. If it has the right resolution, you can stop here.

But SilverStripe comes with a lot of [ready-to-use image manipulating functions](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/files/images/) you can use to crop or resize your Image to fit. If your Slider should be e.g. 600x300px you can use something like:

```
{ src: "$Slideshow1.Fill(600,300).AbsoluteURL"}
```

PS: for solving the "portrait image in a landscape slideshow" problem I always use [Jonom's great focuspoint module](https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-focuspoint) which comes with some additional functions to define the center point of the image for cropping.

Comment: I tried using `$Slideshow1.URL` and after I saw this tried `$Slideshow1.AbsoluteURL` but it kept just putting whatever i typed into the src into the `style="background-image: url($Slideshow1.AbsoluteURL)` instead of the image path.  I'm beginning to think the problem is happening in the JS file from here [Vegas Slideshow JS](https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas/blob/master/src/vegas.js) and not the function that runs the slideshow.  Line 442 is where it grabs the background-image